# Characterizing clique listing vectors

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I am interested in clique listing vectors. i.e. if $G$ is a simple graph over $n$ vertice, then the $\mathcal{K}_s$-listing vector of $G$ is a vector of length $n$ that in its $i$th entry encodes the number of cliques of size $s$ that the vertex $v_i$ participates in.

For the simple case of $s=2$, this vector is simply the *degree sequence* of the graph $G$, and previous results such as the Gale-Ryser Theorem and Erdős–Gallai Theorem state conditions for such vector to correspond to some existing graph $G$.

I wonder if there is existing work on cases where $s\geq 2$.